# SQL error code 1054 unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
create table if not exists applications (
    idResearch int not null, 
    idProf char(10) not null,
    primary key (idResearch, idProf),
    foreign key (idResearch) references research(idResearch),
    foreign key (idProf) references professor(idProf)
);
```

and this is the table:

```
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('10', '123456789');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('10', '432156789');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('10', '789654321');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('11', '876098432');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('11', '234567890');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('12', '432156789');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('12', '789654321');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('13', '876098432');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('14', '876098432');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('14', '987654321');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('15', '432156789');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('16', '123456789');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('16', '432156789');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('16', '789654321');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('17', '789654321');
INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('17', '432156789');
```

> 15:26:13   create table if not exists applications ( idResearch int not null, idProf char(10) not null, primary key (idResearch, idProf), foreign key (idResearch) references research(idResearch), foreign key (idProf) references professor(idProf) )    Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.109 sec

Comment: And where are you getting the error?  Note:  I am a big fan of id columns being auto-incremented columns.

Comment: 0 118 15:01:50 INSERT INTO `university`.`applications` (`idResearch`, `idProf`) VALUES ('10', '123456789') Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'idProf' in 'field list' 0.000 sec

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your posted `INSERT` statement. are you sure there is no special character?

Comment: what do you mean by special character? I don't think so

Comment: Your code (with  minor modifications) works on SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25331).  I suspect you have a bad character in the `create table` statement.  Or two databases with different table structures.

Comment: Can you run a `describe applications`... my guess is the table already existed without that column name, and your create statement didn't actually create the table as it already and existed

Comment: Or u modified table in script didnt drop and recreate it

Comment: I tried to delete the data and do the create table again but now I have other error -0 128 15:26:13 create table if not exists applications (
  idResearch int not null, 
  idProf char(10) not null,
  primary key (idResearch, idProf),
  foreign key (idResearch) references research(idResearch),
  foreign key (idProf) references professor(idProf)
 ) Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.109 sec

Comment: is idProf of type char in the professor table?

Comment: yes @Zelldon. I don't know what is the problem

Comment: Probably because the table being referenced doesn't have an appropriate key for the foreign key reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the syntax in your query, it could be data issue.

Before executing the insert the query, check the following

1. Table 'research' & column 'idResearch' exist
2. Table 'professor' & column 'idProf' exist
3. The reference values (in the insert query) for the columns idResearch, idProf should exist in the research and professor tables resp.

Truncate\delete and drop the 'applications' table manually and then create it once again. Then execute your insert query.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the following in the `foreign key` statements:

```
constraint FKResearch foreign key (idResearch) references research(idResearch),
constraint FKProfessor foreign key (idProf) references professor(idProf)
```

This way, when it encounters an error, MySQL will tell you which of those foreign key constraints is being violated.

Once you know that, you have to check whether the column names are matching, the values you are trying to insert actually have a corresponding father-value in the referenced table, and if the definition of both columns is *exactly* the same (check the collation and the encoding, most of the times the problem lays there).